# Function to plot stock price - why are they plotting together and not individually?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to automate graphing the stock price and its moving averages. I have a list of stocks, I would like to create a chart with the stock's price, its 50 day moving average, and its 200 day moving average. I want to do this for x number of stocks in my list. When I run it, why are they plotting over top of each other on the same graph, rather than individually?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime as dt

stocks = ['AAPL', 'DVN', 'XOM']
start = '2010-01-01'
end = dt.datetime.today()

def plotStock(stock):
    df = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)['Adj Close']
    df.plot()
    pd.rolling_mean(df, 50).plot(style='k')
    pd.rolling_mean(df, 200).plot(style='--')
    plt.title(stock, fontsize=10)
    plt.savefig(stock + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')

for stock in stocks:
    plotStock(stock)
```

Comment: It displays them that way in the graphics viewer, but the way you wrote that, it will still save three separate figures with one stock each. Actually, no, the first figure will have one plot, the second two, and the third all three. If you add `plt.close()` after `plt.savefig()`, then they'll each have one stock each.

Comment: See the edit. You just need to close the viewer after each time.

Answer (score 1):

To have a unique set of axes per lineplot in your figure, you'll need to add subplots.  See [subplot example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) for more details.